# GeoServer distorting circle/buffer

Tags: geoserver, wfs, buffer, rendering, circle

Trying to render a circle and buffer from the WFS link generated by me, with GeoJSON format using Leaflet in an app and QGIS on desktop to render it, the image below was the result.

How do I fix this?

[image: green blob]

Comment: You need to give details about what you tried or commands you issued that created the unwanted result.

Comment: I generated a wfs with geojson and using leaflet and qgis to render it, the image was the result. Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to add all the necessary details as it will help the reader understanding the whole issue without having to sift through the comments.